problem with armature after mirroring part of object
first of all, I'm totally new to blender, but couldn't find my answer after searching a lot. here is my problem in blender 4.2:
in object edit mode, I've duplicated left shoulder top armor, mirrored, moved over right shoulder.

now the problem is; in pose mode if i rotate or modify left shoulder bone, that right mirrored armor part is moving too as in image:

I've tried to separate all object parts, then clear all parents from it, re-assign right shoulder bone as parent. but still it move with left shoulder bone as well as right shoulder bone.
any help appreciated.
blender file:

ps: is there anyway to select a bone and see which objects assigned to that bone? I know about weights and vertex groups, but in this object, non assigned to mirrored object.
